# Perform Method after a button is clicked in a sub window

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a ReturnButton class that adds a new pop up on a MenuItem Click, now  in that sub Window if the 'Save' button is clicked and closed, then i would like  to perform a function in the ReturnButton Class. I just do not know how to go about it. Currently ,when the Return Menu Item is clicked it opens the sub window AND performs all three functions I have at the same time.

```
   } else if (selectedMenuItem.getText().equals("Return ")) {

        RMeditor editor = new RMeditor(pSubmittal); // opensPopUp
        UI.getCurrent().addWindow(editor);


        PServices.getInstance().getDataService().getSDao().changeStatus(submittal,
                    Value.RETURNED);
PServices.getInstance().getDataService().getSDao().sendNotification(submittal,
                    Value.RETURN);

        } 
            }
```

and here is the save button in the pop up window

```
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            if (hasChanges()) {
                ConfirmDialog.show(
                        UI.getCurrent(), 
                        "Confirmation", 
                        "Do you want to discard changes ?", 
                        "Yes", 
                        "No", 
                        new ConfirmDialog.Listener() {

                            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                            @Override
                            public void onClose(ConfirmDialog dialog) {
                                if (dialog.isConfirmed()) {
                                    win.close();
                                }
                                dialog.close();
                            }
                });
            } else {
                win.close();
            }               
        }
    });

    // The Save Button
    saveButton = UIUtils.createSaveButton();
    saveButton.setEnabled(hasChanges() && isFormDataValid());
    saveButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            if (isFormDataValid() && hasChanges()) {

                FDao fDao = PServices.getInstance().getDataService().getFDao();
                fdao.updatePersonTabInfo(pSubmittal, null, null, externalRemarksTextArea.getValue(), internalRemarksTextArea.getValue());
                DefaultNotificationHandler.getInstance().showSuccessNotification("Your changes have been saved");
                win.close();
                close();
            } else if (isFormDataValid()) {
                win.close();
                close();
            }
        }
    });
    saveButton.setEnabled(false);

    persistButtonLayout.addComponents(saveButton, cancelButton);
}
```

Comment: adding the window is no "blocking operation" with vaadin.  so your window gets added to the state/scenegraph for the user and the code afterwards runs after that (assuming, that you dont want to run the `changeStatus/sendNotifcation` code). So you could add an Listener/Callback to your RMEditor and call that in the succes-branch of your save button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar approach as Vaadin uses for buttons and other components. There you add a listener to get notified when something happens.

Create interface for listening successful save

```
interface RmSaveListener extends Serializable {
    void onRmSave(Object submittal);
}
```

Then register listener from where you createm RMeditor:

```
RMeditor editor = new RMeditor(pSubmittal); // opensPopUp
editor.addSaveListener(this::onRmSave);
UI.getCurrent().addWindow(editor);

private void onRmSave(Object submittal) {
    PServices.getInstance().getDataService().getSDao().changeStatus(
            submittal,
            Value.RETURNED);
    PServices.getInstance().getDataService().getSDao().sendNotification(
            submittal,
            Value.RETURN);
}
```

Then you can call your listener from save button

```
@Override
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    if (isFormDataValid() && hasChanges()) {
        if (saveListener != null) {
            saveListener.onRmSave(pSubmittal);
        }
        win.close();
        close();
    } else if (isFormDataValid()) {
        win.close();
        close();
    }
}
```